# Interface Genérica ou uma interface pra cada Repository?

Tags: java, c#, spring, spring-boot, asp.net-core

Em qual situação devemos usar uma interface genérica para todos os Repository e em qual situação devemos usar uma interface para cada Repository?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

Você pode utilizar as duas, de acordo com a sua necessidade. De preferência a "genérica".

Mas falando de Repository, você vai criar uma interface "IRepository" contendo os métodos comuns a todas as classes Repository. Esses métodos obrigatoriamente estarão em todas as Repository.

E para cada Repository você pode definir a interface dela, essa interface herdará da IRepository.